# Plotting a 3D tube composed of ellipses of varying major and minor axes

Tags: matlab, 3d

I am basically trying to make a figure which takes two growth curves of different periodicities over time. 
X is time, 
Y is population 1
Z is population 2 
X, Y, and Z are vectors

For time Xi, I want an ellipse to be drawn on the Y Z plane, with major axis of size Y(Xi) and minor axis of size Z(Xi). Then, I want to mesh across the X plane, to create a tubelike structure.

I have Matlab R2013Aa

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is quite similar to standard uses of meshgrid and surf, except that here, your meshed surface is wrapped around a tube.

I think the code below does what you are looking for:

```
NX=80;         'number of X values
X=1:NX;        'replace with actual X vector
Y=5+cos(X/4);  'replace with actual Y vector
Z=10+sin(X/4); 'replace with actual Z vector

Nth=100;  %number of points around each ellipse
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,Nth);

y=Y'*cos(theta);
z=Z'*sin(theta);
x=repmat(X',1,Nth);
surf(x,y,z);
```

Comment: Excellent. I suggest adding `c = sqrt(y.^2 + z.^2)` and change the call to `surf` into `surf(x,y,z,c)` to get coloring based on distance to x-axis. When I view 3d plots I usually use `axis vis3d` to prevent axes resizing during rotation, which I find very annoying. `daspect([c_x, c_y, c_z])` can be used to change the aspect ratio of the axes, e.g. `daspect([5,1,1])` for 'compressing' the plot along the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jon @Martin!

I want to modify this: I have a time series where time is the X axis, and two series of values compose the y and z axes. I want the mean values to make the center of the tuboid for each X, and the confidence intervals to make up radius. I've done it with an iteration of the 'ellipse' function, but for that I need to make up a confidence interval for the X axis, and I would like these ellipses to be linked into a tuboid, as in the previous case. This is what I have so far

'for i=1:12
    ellipsoid(x(i),y(i),z(i),xc(i),yc(i),zc(i));
    hold on
end'